# SQL Update with Select

Tags: mysql

I want to create the following Update-Statement:
UPDATE table1 SET STATUSID=4 WHERE...

And after the where I want to use a select statement:

```
select f.formtype,f.formuser,f.formstatusid
from table2 v, table1 f
where v.statusid = "1"
and v.date like "2010-06-17 15:40%"
and f.formtype = "4"
and f.formid = v.formid
```

This select statement define the entries, which I want to update. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UPDATE from SELECT using SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table1 AS f
  JOIN table2 AS v ON f.formid = v.formid
SET STATUSID = 4
WHERE v.statusid = "1" AND v.date LIKE "2010-06-17 15:40%" AND f.formtype = "4"
```